# How can I obtain all the IDs from a full join in a single column. (Trying to avoid UNION)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, alias

I am trying to get a count from both test tables in a single column.

```
CREATE TABLE #testA (name VARCHAR(25))  
INSERT INTO #testA VALUES ('A'), ('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G')
CREATE TABLE #testB (name VARCHAR(25))  
INSERT INTO #testB VALUES ('B'),('C'),('D'), ('F'),('J'), ('I'), ('B'), ('B')

SELECT a.name as names , count(a.name) as A_counts, count(b.name) as B_counts
FROM #testA as a 
  FULL JOIN #testB as b 
ON a.name=b.name
GROUP BY names
```

Currently I am getting an error:

> Invalid column name 'names'.

If I change the query without the alias:

```
CREATE TABLE #testA (name VARCHAR(25))  
INSERT INTO #testA VALUES ('A'), ('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G')
CREATE TABLE #testB (name VARCHAR(25))  
INSERT INTO #testB VALUES ('B'),('C'),('D'), ('F'),('J'), ('I'), ('B'), ('B')

SELECT a.name, count(a.name) as A_counts, count(b.name) as B_counts
FROM #testA as a 
  FULL JOIN #testB as b 
ON a.name=b.name
GROUP BY a.name
```

The result shows up *Null* for all values of table #testB.

Comment: Based on the syntax of the query, I changed the database tag to SQL Server.

Comment: If we focus on Name = "B", I see one row in A yet your output shows 3 for both A and B. Is that really your goal? If you want counts based on each table, you must count BEFORE you join.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.name, b.name) as name,
       count(a.name) as A_counts, count(b.name) as B_counts
FROM #testA a FULL JOIN
     #testB b 
     ON a.name = b.name
GROUP BY COALESCE(a.name, b.name);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ef858f694542784c869e2c183597ea9) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want *accurate* counts, you need to aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT coalesce(a.name, b.name) as name,
       coalesce(a.cnt, 0) as A_counts, coalesce(b.cnt, 0) as B_counts
FROM (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from testA a
      group by name
     ) a FULL JOIN
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from testB b 
      group by name
     ) b
     ON a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: I see 1 issue, can you see that the A_count for value B is 3, while it should be 1. How can I fix this?